# Why is the movie titled Roma?

Tags: title, roma

I just finished watching the new Netflix movie [*Roma*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6155172/) (2018). Do you know what its title means?

The word Rome/Roma is not mentioned in the movie as far as remember.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IMDB explains.

> The film's events take place in 1970 and 1971, predominantly in the Colonia **Roma** neighborhood of Mexico City.

as does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roma_(2018_film))

> The title refers to the Colonia **Roma**, a neighborhood in Mexico City

It has nothing to do with Rome...

Answer (score 0):

I wondered the same. I think it is called Roma because it is based on love stories going wrong. And AMOR backwards is ROMA.

Comment: ... what does that have anything to do with "amor"

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Do you have any reason to believe this instead of the existing answer that cites iMDB?